# Database back up from mvc.net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using VS2010 and working on mvc application. I want to get Database backup from c# code and then want to restore database.

If some one has solution then please reply.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I am using sql server database

Comment: Some body has the solution for my query?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform database backups using T-SQL script see this MSDN help page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Then you could wrap it as a Stored Procedure and execute it from your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about your question as with two parts. First - Transact SQL script on how to backup and restore database, and second - how to run this script from ASP.Net, simply .NET for general purposes. Both are independent of each other. Answer of 1st question is as Sam adviced, look at [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx). For the second sample, you could take a look at [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), using the first answer with it. For more general purposes, you could take a look at [.NET Data Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817654%28pandp.10%29.aspx), but i don't think you will need this one for now